# requestPermission in Fragment not show dialog

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-gps

I have a fragment with an ImageView.
When the user click this image I would like to request the permission for the localization but despite the "requestPermission()" is executed, the request dialog is not showed.

My fragment onCreateView method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View center = inflater.inflate(R.layout.board, container, false);
    position = (ImageView) center.findViewById(R.id.position);

    position.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "I need the permission pls",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, LOCALIZATION_PERMISSION);

                }
            }
        }
    });
    return center;
}
```

NOTE :: shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is never true. I verify that with the debugger.

I managed the permission in the Manifest also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="it.peoople">

    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permissions android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="it.peoople.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="it.peoople.floating.Messaging"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="it.peoople.floating.Registration"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

NOTE :: The permission dialog never appeared, so I never check "don't ask again".

Every time request permissions is executed is automatically denied and the Android logcat print this line

```
10-09 18:22:50.019 2223-2359/it.peoople D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
10-09 18:22:50.020 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 5411
10-09 18:22:50.020 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Using measurement service
10-09 18:22:50.020 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Connecting to remote service
10-09 18:22:50.025 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Activity paused, time: 57774748
10-09 18:22:50.030 2223-2254/it.peoople D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=5411, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Registration, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1569558894460098554}]
10-09 18:22:50.043 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Using measurement service
10-09 18:22:50.043 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
10-09 18:22:50.050 2223-2254/it.peoople D/FA: Connected to remote service
10-09 18:22:50.050 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
10-09 18:22:50.082 2223-2254/it.peoople V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 57774811
10-09 18:22:50.082 2223-2518/it.peoople D/AppTracker: App Event: start
```

Please help me.

Really thanks.

Comment: what is your target sdk version ?

Comment: target SDK 25, minSDK 21

Comment: and Build version of testing device ? Its working fine for me

Comment: My code working fine for you? I testing on a OnePlus3 7.1.1

Comment: yes, same code working fine for me.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Which is the Android OS version of the device where this code is not working?

Comment: I test this app on different devices 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

i think you should move this to the activity and implement a new listener to interact with it from the fragment.

your problem is that you never execute the toast you just build it but nevet call .show() on it.

but the dialog you are looking for is not a build in feature of android you need to build it yourself as follow:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.permission_prompt_location);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        SwipeActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
```

Comment: I forgot the .show forse the Toast, but I verify that the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is never true with the debugger.

Comment: Is this a real device or emulated?

Comment: is a real device

Comment: Try to turn on the location permission from the app settings just to see if the if statement will change it's behavior.  Also try to comment out the if statement of the sdk version

Comment: Man , where is the "else" in your second if statement? Do me a favor , just try the code I wrote in this answer it's working for me

Comment: first of all thanks for the help. I tried your code and a simple dialog appaered but when i click ok button I am not given the permissions equally.

Comment: I already tried to set the permissions in application settings but there are no permissions to grant. I'm really confudes

Comment: You are welcome, if you don't see the permission in the app settings it means that your manifest is not set up right, put the manifest in your question let's see what goes on there

Comment: the manifest is now in the question. Really thanks for the help

Comment: That is so weird , by the look of it you should see the permission in your app settings, the only thing i can think of is to clear your project and build it again mybe that&#39;s the problem

Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: I think you should open a new question about the location permission because that is your bug , when you&#39;ll see tge location permission in your app settings everything else should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (String permission)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(java.lang.String))

instead of [`boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Activity activity, String permission)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)).